# JSF and CDI with inputFile component

Tags: java, jsf, cdi

I made a simple xhtml page for upload file by using `<h:inputFile>` component. And everything works fine. And in managed bean I used dependency injection for the `Logger`. I used a factory class and `createLogger()` method in, to enable injection for object of `Logger` class. 
Everything is ok but, nothing works without a `@Model` annotation in managed bean.

Can somebody explain the meaning of the `@Model` annotation.

I can not find on internet proper explanation. A founded explanation of other annotation like as `@Session`, `@Request`, `@Application` etc.

What does the `@Model` annotation do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej vmaric,

`@Model` == `@RequestScoped` + `@Named`

It exposes the `Backing Bean` directly to your `JSF 2` or `JSP` and its context will be destroyed after the end of the servlet request.

So it should not be used for entities.

Here is a hint from the [Weld Reference Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.1-Final/en-US/html_single/):

Notice the controller bean is request-scoped and named. Since this combination is so common in web applications, there's a built-in annotation for it in CDI that we could have used as a shorthand. When the (stereotype) annotation @Model is declared on a class, it creates a request-scoped and named bean.

Comment: I can put it there @RequestScoped and @Named("sample") end it is same like @Model? Or it can be SessionScoped bean?
What is explanation for Model annotation then? Why we need it?

Comment: The Context of RequestScoped Beans will destroyed after the Servlet request ends, the SessionScoped Beans Context lives until your Browsersession is up.

Comment: Yes I now this. Bath why we need @Model when we have SessionScoped or RequesScoped annotations!

Comment: To save time because only write ´@Model´ instead of ´@Named("name")´ and ´@RequestScoped´  ...that we could have used as a shorthand.